# JS bluebird promise error gives no detail

Tags: javascript, error-handling, promise, bluebird

I'm using bluebird promise with Node.js, after a long piece of code Promise caught an error and when I tried to print out the error message, all it said was:

```
[ReferenceError: i is not defined]
```

Is there anything I can do to get more details of the error, like the number of line that made this happen?

Comment: Try to print the whole error, including the `.stack`, not only the `.message`.

Answer (score 0):

While using Promise, I tend to catch error like so:

```
return User.findOne({
    id: someId
}).then(function(foundUser) {
    // do something
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

If I just remove the catch mechanism, Node.js will print out all the error stack trace for me...